# How can I encrypt files in a file transfer website?

Tags: encryption, web-application, decryption, key-generation

I am a complete beginner and have almost no knowledge of encryption.

I have a file transfer website that encrypt the files before saving them in the server then it decrypts the files to be ready to download. The problem is the encryption key. For obvious reasons I can't store the encryption key in the server. I cannot use a private key since the recipient might have never visited the website (and there can be multiple recipients), so the public key for the recipient won't be generated to encrypt the file in the first place.

I am out of options. What is the industry standard? What do websites such as WeTransfer and TransferNow do? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt the files on the server. Against whom you want to protect the files from? Does encryption really help here, assuming that the attacker and the user downloading the file essentially have the same knowledge about the encryption of the file in your scenario?

Comment: Lets say that the attacker somehow has access to the server, I want to protect the files by encrypting them. This also gives the user a sense of confidence in the website if they know that administrators cannot access the files. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: OP, What you are trying to build sounds similar to [Firefox Send](https://blog.mozilla.org/en/products/firefox/introducing-firefox-send-providing-free-file-transfers-while-keeping-your-personal-information-private/) (which is no longer active).  Files are encrypted in the sender's browser using a symmetric AES key and are decrypted in the recipient's browser using the same AES key.  The key is encoded in the path part of a URL (after the #) which is sent to the recipient out-of-band.  The server only sees the encrypted file, and never sees the plaintext file or the key.

Comment: Thank you, this would work. But how can I make the files time limited without deleting them from the server. Obviously I can remove the download link, but the encryption key will still be in the URL and in the browser history, wifi history... Is this possible @mti2935

Comment: You're welcome.  Disabling access to the file is one option.  But I don't think this requirement can be implemented cryptographically, as there is no way to disable the use of a key to decrypt a file during a certain window of time.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183367/time-limited-encryption and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89094/ensure-that-a-file-can-only-be-decrypted-after-a-specific-date for some interesting reading on this subject.

Comment: This is the same question you asked yesterday. I'm closing as t he other question included more information (including your understanding of end-to-end encryption)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate

Comment: I agree with @schroeder, this question is indeed very similar to yesterday's question.  OP, I think the crux of both questions is whether to use symmetric encryption, or asymmetric encryption.  The problem that you described yesterday seemed like a classic application for asymmetric encryption, whereas this question has a slightly different wrinkle, i.e. '*I cannot use a private key since..., so the public key for the recipient won't be generated to encrypt the file in the first place.*'.  With this being the case, symmetric encryption might be a better solution.